# Линейный метод java

Tags: java

Если введенного слова нет в поисковом массиве, как вывести это на экран? 
(как применить переменную `boolean`, когда `true`, тогда выводится как в данном коде, а когда `false`, то "ничего не найдено").

```
public class MagicSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите слово?: ");
        String word = scn.nextLine();           
        String[] str = { "Масло", "Вода", "Дерево", "Помидор", "Сельдерей", "Кувшин" };         
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                System.out.println("Ваше слово: \n*" + word + "* найдено " + "с индексом " + i + " !!!");

            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Оформите ваш алгоритм в виде boolean метода. + после System.out.println вам необходим break/return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Есть вот такой способ более наглядный через стримы:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите слово?: ");
        String word = scn.nextLine();
        String[] str = {"Масло", "Вода", "Дерево", "Помидор", "Сельдерей", "Кувшин"};
        long countWord = Stream.of(str) 
                            .filter(s -> s.equals(word))
                            .count();
        if(countWord>0){
            System.out.println("Слово найдено");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Слово не найдено");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить нужно всего две строчки:

```
public class MagicSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите слово?: ");
        String word = scn.nextLine();           
        String[] str = { "Масло", "Вода", "Дерево", "Помидор", "Сельдерей", "Кувшин" }; 

        // Добавляем флажок, по умолчанию значение `false`
        boolean found = false;  

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                System.out.println("Ваше слово: \n*" + word + "* найдено " + "с индексом " + i + " !!!");

                // Если слово найдено, меняем значение флажка
                found = true;
            }           
        }   

        // Если слово не было найдено, то и флажок значение не поменяет
        // => выводим в консоль, что слова нет
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Слово не найдено"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если слово найдено на первой итерации, ради чего совершать остальные 99999 итераций, которые пройдут впустую?

Comment: @test123 с чего вы взяли, что слово будет один раз в массиве? Об этом не было сказано. Если же так, то добавить `break;` не составит труда.

Comment: хорошо, убедили :D

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @НикитаТелегин если ответ вас удовлетворяет, примите его как правильный. Для этого нажмите на галочку, которая чуть левее самого ответа.

Comment: Да, конечно, через 4 минуты сделаю это)!

Answer (score 0):

**Как вариант можно вот так сделать:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите слово?: ");
        String word = scn.nextLine();
        String[] str = {"Масло", "Вода", "Дерево", "Помидор", "Сельдерей", "Кувшин"};
        System.out.println(Stream.of(str)
                .filter(s -> s.equals(word))
                .findFirst()
                .map(s -> "Слово есть")
                .orElse("Слова нет"));
    }
```

**Вывод:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]